# web socket Lost Connection to stompEndPoint in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-websocket

i have created a web-socket in spring boot and deployed it in Cloud foundry.
In localhost it is running fine but in cloud foundry it is saying **Lost Connection to stompEndPoint**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
stomp.min.js:8 
Opening Web Socket...
abstract-xhr.js:132 
GET https://"CF APP URL"/websocket-example/info?t=1536076909829 404 (Not Found)
Whoops! Lost connection to https://"CF APP URL"/websocket-example

Here is the code:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    private static final Logger LOG = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);  
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        try {
            stompEndpointRegistry
                .addEndpoint("/websocket-example")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            LOG.error("WebSocketConfig in Exception : {}. Caused by: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
```

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: HTTP 404 means that the resource you're requesting cannot be found. Are you sure you have the right URL? It's possible it could be different in CF? Unlike a lot of environments, CF will deploy your app in the root context path. Also, check your browser's Dev Tools for possibly more information (JS Console & Network panels).

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply , I have taken URL from CF using command "cf apps", so my URL is correct, The log that i've mentioned in the question is from console only.

Comment: What provider are you using? Where are you running your app? Some providers use a different port for WebSockets, you might be hitting that.

Comment: I have deployed my application in cloud foundry , Its not a pivotal cloud foundry.

Comment: Cloud foundry Uses 8080 port by default . i tried giving host and port also its not working . eg: var socket = new SockJS('https://<HOST>:8080/websocket-example');  Log is saying lost connection to https://<HOST>:8080/websocket-example

Comment: It does not use port 8080. That is the internal port to which your application should listen, but your Javascript should make requests to your application on the standard port 443, unless otherwise noted by your CF provider (some CF providers, like Pivotal Web Services use the non-standard port 8443). Requests to your app are received by a load balancer on standard ports, they are then sent to the Gorouters, which handle routing to your specific application and make sure the traffic comes in on port 8080.

Comment: Hi Daniel , I checked in the network call my all the websocket call are going to 443 port only.                                                                                                   Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 52.29.218.151:443

Comment: You can see here the remote address port is 443, it means my application is running in 443 port , and i tried giving 443 port from my java script as well , It is saying Not found.

Comment: What do you get if you run `cf curl /v2/info | grep "doppler"`? It should print the websocket URL that is used to fetch logs on your platform. Check if that is reporting port 443 or something else? You need to use the port reported in that URL.

Comment: If that's correct, run `cf logs <your-app>`. Then make the WebSocket connection. Check the log output. You should see a line marked `[RTR/X]`, this is an access log entry from the router. Confirm it has the right request. Your should be something like `"GET /websocket-example`. The number right after that is the HTTP status. A success should be a 101, which indicates the protocol was switched to WSS. If you see anything else, it's not an issue with the platform and you need to debug your app more. Add additional logging, turn the log levels up, etc..